# max floating point value

Tags: c, floating-point, precision, limits

I've just started learning floating point binary encoding deeper and got myself confused. In C limits defined max value for float:

> FLT_MAX      = 3.402823e+38

What i don't understand is if we have:

> FLT_MAX_EXP     = 128

That means for normalized binary numbers we will have implicit bit equal 2^128 if we try to get FLT_MAX. So FLT_MAX in binary should look like this:

> **Sign**: 0 **Exponent**: 11111111 **Mantissa**: 00000000000000000000000

What means we have 23 unused bits and we've already got max number.
But if we used that bits we could get a number like 2 times larger than defined FLT_MAX.

Could you clarify to me this point?

Also I need explanation about how exactly negative exponent is present. If in my case we use for it 8 bits with no sign bit at all. I understand that we can represent sign in 1 or 2's complement as most significant bit. But we use biased exponent and we have all bits for exponent magnitude. If it is so how binary negative and positive exponent different. How exactly we define sign of biased exponent?

I would be very grateful if someone explained calculations on max and min binary 32 floating point values in binary showing binary arithmetics standing by it. Like:
Binary presentation -> conversion to decimal -> decimal presentation.

Comment: Your binary discussion applies to a [certain format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) for `float`.  C does not specify that usage, although it is commonly employed.  Other `float` formats exist.  Portable C code does not depend on a select format.